# How do I remove observations from the first level of a variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, levels

I have a factor variable movieFac and I'm trying to remove these 38 observations at the beginning and recreate the variable without them. I've been trying drop levels, but haven't had any success.

```
movieFac <- as.factor(movieW$movie)
table(movieFac)
movieFac
                                                     A Beautiful Mind 
                              38                                   23 
                 American Beauty                               Batman 
                              38                                   13 
               Beverly Hills Cop                              Chicago 
                              33                                   36
```

Comment: that data is considered " " and not a NA value, can you share your data ?

Comment: try `table(grep('\\w', movieW$movies, value = TRUE))`

Comment: what does `dput(levels(as.factor(movieW$movie)))` return? It's likely you have zero length strings. You can get rid of those doing `movieW <- subset(movieW, movie != "")` first.